# Is there a way to return implementing struct instead of the interface in Go?

Tags: go

I want to build a system that can be extended for different applications of the system.

In the domain package, I have an interface as the following:

```golang
package main

type CardInterface interface {
 GetName()string
}

type DeckInterface interface {
 GetCards()[]CardInterface
}
```

and in the application package I have the following implementations:

```golang
package implementation
//Implementing CardInterface
type Card struct {
  Name string
}

func (c Card) GetName() string {
  return c.Name
}


type Deck struct {
  Cards []Card
}


func (d Deck) GetCards() []CardInterface {
  return d.Cards[]
}
```

But it gives an error saying that Can not return an instance of `[]Card` instead of `[]CardInterface` .

Is there a way to implement this kind of OOP structure in Go? If not how can I achieve this kind of extension capability?

Comment: You've declared your interface and you've declared an implementation for that interface. What is the problem? Is the code not working? Are you getting a compiler error? If so, please provide the error. If the code is working what is your question?

Comment: I think the answer to your question is "no", but I don't see any reason why the interfaces exist here. How many different implementations can a deck and cards have?

Comment: You need to manually convert (using a loop) a value of `[]Card` to `[]CardInterface`. Go will not do this for you: https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface.

Comment: Sorry you are right, I've provided the error given by the compiler.

Comment: https://play.golang.com/p/bs34WyL5iE0 is what you need to do to get rid of the compiler error.

Comment: @PaulHankin think of it more like a trading card system. The deck will have more methods like `Draw(count int) []CardInterface` which can deny you or lets you draw in consequences in different implementations.

Comment: @mkopriva thank you, I will use this method. Although it seems cumbersome, it's nice to be able to do that. Thanks again to both of you!

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/6bMKSIXliHA here what you want to do may be

Comment: The underlying problem might be that you cannot write Java code in Go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to preserve the `Deck` type definition (if not, check out [Shadowchaser's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61301778/11378605)), you can try something like this:

```
func (d Deck) GetCards() []CardInterface {
  var res []CardInterface
  for _ , card := range d.Cards {
    res = append(res, card)
  }
  return res
}
```

You need to reslice the `Deck` since, while a `Card` is a `CardInterface`, a `[]Card` is not a `[]CardInterface`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your Deck like this:

```
type Deck struct {
    Cards []CardInterface
}
```

You also don't need `[]` here:

```
func (d Deck) GetCards() []CardInterface {
    return d.Cards
}
```

You'll of course need type assertion to access Card in Cards array, here's example of how it can work https://play.golang.org/p/PPofF2u-H3S.